# Highlist border of WPF combobox when iskeyboardfocused

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

This is my first posting on stackoverflow.

I have made my own combobox, which inherits from combobox. I am using it in editable mode only.

I want to paint the border blue, when the combobox has keyboardfocus, just like we see on textboxes.

I have an XAML-solution, that works perfect, but i want to do it in code-behind, because i am placing the combobox in a DLL, and i have problems with ressoucefiles and DLLs.

The XAML below works. But i want it in code-behind.

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}">
                    <Border x:Name="splitBorder" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                        <Path x:Name="arrow" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Fill="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Glyph}" Data="F1 M 0,0 L 2.667,2.66665 L 5.3334,0 L 5.3334,-1.78168 L 2.6667,0.88501 L0,-1.78168 L0,0 Z"/>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>



                    <!--This paint the border blue -->
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <!--This paint the border blue -->

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

I have tried:

```
protected override void OnGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var parent = (Border)editableTextBox.Parent;
    parent.BorderBrush = Brushes.Blue;
    parent.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);

    base.OnGotKeyboardFocus(e);
}
```

This is not working.  It is  painting the border of the inner textbox.

I have also tried:

```
var template = this.Template;
var myControl = template.FindName("templateRoot", this);
Debug.Print(myControl.GetType().ToString());
```

It prints: "System.Windows.Controls.Grid", telling that templateRoot is a Grid. So there is no border.

But if i read the XAML correctly,it says that templateRoot is a border.

What am i doing wrong? It is the wrong templateRoot that i am finding?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
editableTextBox.BorderThickness = new Thickness(10);
editableTextBox.BorderBrush = Brushes.Green;
```

Comment: Hi Martin, This only paints the inner border, and not the border around the dropdown-button. I am using the combobox in editmode.